# PHP if comparison when Array involved

Tags: php

I have an IF statement that I can't seem to get right as far as it ever failing to be true.  Here is the code:

```
        file_put_contents('php.txt', $_POST['columns'][$i], FILE_APPEND);
        if ( $_POST['columns'][$i] != 'TimeOccurred' ) {
            if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'])."%' ";
        }
```

The output from my file_put_contents is as follows:

TimeOccurred.date.truetrueArray

I need to find a way to see if this is the "TimeOccurred" column and if it is filter the results in a different way.  I have tried playing with implode/explode on the periods to break this up into three strings.  I have tried converting $_POST['columns'][$i] to a string and then breaking it up.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

********EDIT*********

Am I doing this correctly?  I don't get any output at all:

Tried this outside the for statement:

```
var_dump($_POST['columns']);
```

Tried this inside the for statement:

```
var_dump($_POST['columns'][$i]);
```

I don't get output from either of them.  For some reason just doing a var_dump causing a json error when the page is loading, not sure why a random var_dump in middle of a php file would have any effect on the json data coming back since it doesn't actually change anything if I understand it correctly.  I test var_dump on completely different variable that wasn't an array and it still just causes the json error and never returns a value.

******EDIT 2******

Thought it might help if I mention that the php file in question is called via AJAX and returns json encoded data. Is it trying to encode the var_dump and send it along too?

*****EDIT 3*******

I was able to get the var_export to work properly.  Here are the results.

```
  array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'Action',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     1 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'TimeOccurred.date.',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     2 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'PerformedByUserName',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     3 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'IPv4From',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     4 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'ObjectAffected',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     5 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'ObjectClass',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     6 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'AttributeAffected',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     7 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'AttributeValueAdded',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     8 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'AttributeValueRemoved',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),

     9 => 
  array (
    'data' => 'AdditionalDetailRegardingSelectedAttributes',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),
     10 => 
  array (
   'data' => 'FromServer',
    'name' => '',
    'searchable' => 'true',
    'orderable' => 'true',
    'search' => 
    array (
      'value' => '',
      'regex' => 'false',
    ),
  ),
)
```

So I guess I really need to do something like:

```
if ( $_POST['columns'][$i][data] != 'TimeOccurred.date' )
```

Does that seem like I'm on the right path?  Going to do some of my own testing as well.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['columns'][$i])` show?

Comment: It sounds like `$_POST['columns'][$i]` is an array, you need to index it to get what you want.

Comment: `addslashes()` is not sufficient.  You are wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, it's clearly an array, since you use `$_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value']` later. Add the `var_dump()` to the question, and explain what you're trying to test.

Comment: Am I doing this correctly both of these aren't providing any output at all:

Comment: Yep the var_dump output will be included with the ajax response and break it. In your file_put_contents call use `var_export($_POST['columns'][$i], true)` so if its an array it actually shows what's in it rather than printing 'Array'.

Comment: Thank you for showing me var_export as an option.  So many little problems I can figure out on my own if I can just see what data is in the array/variable vs what I expect to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the comments to my initial question helped me figure out how to properly export the values of my array, I was able to understand how to get my IF statement to work as expected:

```
if ( $_POST['columns'][$i]['data'] != 'TimeOccurred.date.' ) {
            if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'])."%' ";
        }
```

To be clear I realize there are some SQL Injection issues here.  For now this is just an internal proof of concept, I will be concerned with closing up SQL Injection vulnerabilities it just wasn't relevant to this individual question.  If I need help with that I will create a separate post.